# Disabling other tabs when clicked on a button

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I would like to disable tab selection when clicking on a button. For this I am using the following code:

```
        foreach (TabPage page in scenarioSelectionTab.TabPages)
        {
            if (scenarioSelectionTab.SelectedTab != page) page.Enabled = false;
        }
```

The problem is, when I use the code above, this disables the current tab as well. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Feel free to include the appropriate tags in your post (WinForms?)

Comment: Your code works fine to me

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I am using this in button_click event, can it be the issue?

Comment: According to the documentation, the `TabPage.Enabled` property is not meaningful. It's likely just setting the `TabControl.Enabled` property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
foreach (TabPage page in scenarioSelectionTab.TabPages) {
    ((Control)page).Enabled = scenarioSelectionTab.SelectedTab == page;
}
```

TabPage class DON'T have working Enabled property. Read MSDN.

If this don't work, try another variant with selected event:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (e.TabPage != scenarioSelectionTab.SelectedTab) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: This also disables the current one. :/

Comment: Then you have to remove the tabs and re-add it when you want it.

Comment: I re-added the tab control and it worked unexpectedly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm added another solution with selecting event. But if you resolved your issue with adding/removing tabs then OK.

Comment: @EldarAgalarov can you explain what casting to `Control` you think should do? Polymorphism is not here any more?

Answer (score 1):

You are only disabling pages - that's why when you can't enable another tab. Just set `Enabled` state for each tab page:

```
foreach (TabPage page in scenarioSelectionTab.TabPages)
{
    page.Enabled = scenarioSelectionTab.SelectedTab == page;
}
```

Comment: @EldarAgalarov nope, OP always skip current page. If it was disabled, it will stay disabled. And all other pages will be disabled as well

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The same issue :/. It disables the current anyway. I am using this in button_click event, can it be the issue?

Comment: @www nope, it cannot be the issue (btw I'm also using button_click event for tests). Make sure your code is exactly same as above

Comment: Unfortunately not working :/. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Yes. I dont know but this is also working after re-adding the TabControl.